# SUM with WHERE col IN and COUNT of GROUP BY subquery = funny math

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total count of each GROUP where two words are used on a page together. For example, I have a word that appears **83** times on is own and another word that appears **22** times on its own, but within the same group (`GROUP BY Book, Chapter, Page`) they appear together **2** times, so I expect to get **2** from my query::

```
"SELECT SUM(pagetotal) AS total
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Page) AS pagetotal 
FROM Books
WHERE Word IN ('Apples', 'Oranges')
GROUP BY BookID, Chapter, Page
) AS t ";
```

This gives me a SUM of **103**, which is clearly the opposite of what I want (it seems to be adding the individual usages of the word "Apples" (**83**) with that of "Oranges" (**22**), then SUBTRACTING the **two** pages where they're used together!) I've tried it with other entries in the column together and get the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. (I have no idea what you are trying to do here.)

Comment: Would you post several rows data and the expected result (in row format)?

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? You should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using in order to only get answers that work for you.

Comment: Relatively new to this and still trying to figure out "how to post" around here. That being said, I had to google DBMS (I'm that much of a noob). MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY BookID, Chapter, Page` gives you one result row per book page. `COUNT(DISTINCT Page)` tells you how many pages are in the page, which is one, the page itself, obviously. You then add up all those ones to get the total number of pages one of the words exists in.

What you seem to want instead is the pages where both words appear in, for which you count them individually per page:

```
SELECT
  BookID, Chapter, Page,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Apples' THEN 1 END) as apples,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Oranges' THEN 1 END) as oranges,
  COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM Books
WHERE Word IN ('Apples', 'Oranges')
GROUP BY BookID, Chapter, Page
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Apples' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Oranges' THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY BookID, Chapter, Page;
```

If you just want the number of pages where both words occur together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT BookID, Chapter, Page,
  FROM Books
  WHERE Word IN ('Apples', 'Oranges')
  GROUP BY BookID, Chapter, Page
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Apples' THEN 1 END) > 0
     AND COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Oranges' THEN 1 END) > 0
) pages_with_both_words;
```

The message of using `CASE WHEN` inside an aggreagtion function, as in `COUNT(CASE WHEN Word = 'Oranges' THEN 1 END)` is called conditional aggregation by the way. The standard SQL for this is:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE Word = 'Oranges')
```

but only few DBMS support this, yet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick (and useful and not nitpicky 'how to post') answer. Much appreciated! One quick additional question. In my code I'm binding as an array to avoid sql injections, so the placeholder is actually a variable. Should I explode that into individual variables, or is there a way to do the HAVING clause in the case that the words are in a variable together?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't answer the question in your first comment. You can count distinct words in the having clause in order to avoid repeating the variables. The where clause guarantees we are looking at the two words only; `having count(distinct word) = 2` then guarantees that both words are on the page. (An alternative would be to simply remove the where clause, but that could slow down the query significantly.)